# deleting test case from tfs server permanently

Tags: tfs, testcase, tfs-workitem

I want to delete a test case from tfs server by the use of rest api version 2.2 with DELETE http://server:port/{path_to_project}/_apis/test/Plans/{id}/suites/{id}/testcases/{id}?api-version=2.2

but the test case is not deleted, its just removed from the test suite.

When I try to delete the work item (with the id of the test case) by
DELETE http://server:port/{path_to_project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}?api-version=2.2

I get
"message": "VS402838: The work item 196122 cannot be deleted. Test Case work items cannot be deleted."
Is there any way to delete work item for permanently by REST API?

Comment: From the web are you success to delete it? maybe it's a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could not be able to delete test cases from work item stored.

> We dont support yet the deletion of test artifacts (test plan, test
>   suites and test cases) from Work Item store, tough we allow deletion
>   of them from test store. We have this item on our backlog to cleanup
>   work item store as well and bring consistency. As of today, it is a
>   known issue and we are working on it with very high priority. As it
>   becomes available, we will notify users.

You must be a member of the Project Administrators group or have the Delete test artifacts permission set to Allow. **You must also have your access level set to Advanced**, which provides access to the full Test feature set. Users with Basic access and with permissions to permanently delete work items and manage test artifacts can only delete orphaned test cases. That is, they can delete test cases created from Work that aren't linked to any test plans or test suites.

[image]
For more details take a look at this official tutorial-- [Delete test artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=vsts&tabs=browser#delete-test-artifacts)

If you want to use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/test%20cases/delete?view=vsts-rest-5.0) to achieve this, try to use below format and change the API version to meet your TFS version. Note: Since not sure about which version of TFS you are using, this api may not work with your TFS version. Which make sense, some vsts api is new and do not compatible/ work on old TFS version.

```
DELETE https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/testcases/{testCaseId}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```